# error while deploying flask to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am new to flask and GAE. I am trying to deploy a simple flask app to GAE. I am using https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template/ as the template for deploying.

When I run

> dev_appserver.py src/

I get the following error -

```
Debugged import:

- 'application' found in '/home/murtaza/workspace/flask/sim-sim/src/application/__init__.py'.
- 'application.settings' not found.
```

Below is the code from the application.settings file -

```
"""
Initialize Flask app

"""

from flask import Flask

app = Flask('application')
app.config.from_object('application.settings')

import urls
```

What is the utility of application.settings, is it a GAE or flask config file, or a custom file for the above template that can be ignored ?

Any other templates / approaches for deploying flask on GAE? Or sample flask project on GAE?

Comment: Does `application.settings` exist?

Comment: I have a file called settings.py. So is the name correct or should it be changed ?

Comment: The settings.py file is in the folder called application. So is the module name 'application.settings' correct ?

Comment: Thanks got it working, the file name was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a flask config. Take a look here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#configuring-from-files

I haven't tried this, but it looks like a decent start: https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template/

There are also a bunch of other boilerplate templates if you google for it.